# What can be best appropriate HBase schema for RDBMS table

Tags: hbase

I am just beginner to HBase. I want to migrate RDBMS table to HBase.

Table schema in RDBMS is somewhat like this :

```
Field            Type              Collation          Null    Key     Default  Extra             Privileges                       Comment
---------------  ----------------  -----------------  ------  ------  -------  ------------  --  -------------------------------  -------
id               int(16) unsigned  (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)       auto_increment  select,insert,update,references         
user_id          varchar(64)       latin1_swedish_ci  NO      MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
type_id          int(11)           (NULL)             NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
application_id   int(16) unsigned  (NULL)             YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
title            varchar(128)      latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
body             text              latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
posted_time      datetime          (NULL)             YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
template_params  text              latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
count            int(11)           (NULL)             YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
reference_id     int(16)           (NULL)             YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
viewer_id        varchar(64)       latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references
```

Here body and templete have json data in varchar format. Now i want to create schema for this table in HBase.

Operation performed on this data :

```
1. Activity retrival for a user id
2. Activity retrival for a viewer id
3. Activity retrival for particular type_id/particular type_id and user_id.
4. Activity retrival made after t time.
```

What will be the appropiate schema for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
4. Activity retrival made after t time.
```

This will not be so much a problem; HBase stores everything with timestamps, and you can query for all entries after time t.

As for 1, 2 and 3, are you trying to make access fast? If so, I recommend creating three separate tables that will store the data - yes, there is redundancy, but queries will be fast.

1. Use user_id as row key, and store the rest of the values in the columns
2. Use viewer_id as row key, and store rest of the values in the columns
3. Use type_id AND user_id as row key, with type_id in front of user_id. This way, you can query by type_id if only that is provided, and by type_id and user_id if both are provided. (Note that you will have to scan here, and not use the regular get().)

You can code this using [HappyBase](http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) Python library as follows:

```python
con = happybase.Connection()
user = conn.table('user')
viewer = conn.table('viewer')
type_user = conn.table('type_user')

def insert (user_id, viewer_id, type_id):
  user.put (user_id, {'viewer_id': viewer_id, 'type_id': type_id})
  viewer.put (viewer_id, {'user_id': user_id, 'type_id': type_id})
  type_user.put (type_id + user_id, {'viewer_id': viewer_id})

def get_user (user_id):
  return user.row(user_id)

def get_viewer (viewer_id):
  return viewer.row(viewer_id)

def get_type_user (type_id, user_id):
  if user_id == "":
    rowkey = type_id
  else
    rowkey = type_id + user_id
  # Note that we use a scan here to match only type_id if it exists
  return type_user.scan(row_prefix=rowkey)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful for me. By the way, I am using Java and kundera with HBase